# "@echo on" for a post build event batch file in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I'd occationally like to see the actual build event script for debugging purposes.  I've tried leading the script with @echo on which should work according to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0bktkzs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but I've yet to see anything other than exe or explicit "echo some text" output in the build output.

Here's my build event:

```
echo on
cd $(ProjectDir)_dev
PostBuildEvents.bat $(ConfigurationName) $(TargetName)
```

I do see this text in the output, but nothing from within the .bat file.  I also tried added echo on to the top of the batch file but that did not work either.

Answer (score 23):

Although the answer will come incredibly late, it may be useful for other people coming here: the only way I have found is also contained in the documentation page, and it's the following:

> Modify your project settings to collect more than the default amount
>   of information in the build log. On the **Tools** menu, click **Options**. In
>   the **Options** dialog box, click the **Projects and Solutions** node and then
>   click the **Build and Run** node. Then, in the **MSBuild project build log
>   file verbosity** box, click **Detailed**.

[image]

Comment: This does indeed solve this issue but in return you get detailed output for anything you build, which I'm afraid is often not what people want. It's still a good suggestion for debugging purposes though!

Comment: Personally I have found setting the details to normal have been sufficient and it does not give you loads of details you don't want

Comment: 'Normal' has worked for seeing the stdout of programs run in the Post-Build

Answer (score 8):

I was struggling with the same problem. The only way I was able to overcome this was to echo each line, but that was requiring to type everything twice, once for echo and once to execute. So I decided to use variables with echo.

```
ECHO ON
ECHO C:\myFolder\bin\heat.exe
C:\myFolder\bin\heat.exe
if errorlevel 1 exit 1
```

a better way with variables

```
ECHO ON
SET vCmdl="C:\myFolder\bin\heat.exe" 
ECHO %vCmdl%
%vCmdl%
if errorlevel 1 exit 1
```

In this way, I can see each line of the bat file in the Output window and any messages that they produce and if error occurs "exit 1" is received by VS and build FAILS.

Answer (score 5):

One option is to have the Post-Build Event use `cmd /c` to launch a batch script, which will have *echo on by default*.

**For example:**

```
cmd /c PostBuildStep.cmd "$(MSBuildProperty1)" "$(MSBuildProperty2)"
```

Comment: Thanks. This works in VS 2017 with MSBuild project build output verbosity: Minimal.